# Reload image if Content-Type in header is text/html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, curl

I have image generator that sometimes fails and sends a error in text/html while the Status is still 200.

What is the best way to reload the image from the same url if the content-type is not image/jpeg. Should I approach this in a separate php file with curl headers and reload if it's not image/jpeg or is it possible to do on client side in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the image generator script to capture exception and try again. At least return status 500 instead.

Comment: You should probably figure out why it fails. Looking at logs and stuff. Maybe it is a memory issue.

Comment: It's due to a buggy php extension module (not up to date or something, host is uncooperative) can't really fix it from this side.

Comment: Then I guess wrapping it around `try-catch` and handling the exception is your best choice. Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php